# CE 1.9.2 - Custom sales_order_save_after observer fires twice

Tags: event-observer, module, ce-1.9.2.0

This has been driving me crazy for the last few hours now. I created a module to test sending Suppliers a custom email only once the order has been paid for (Order status changes to `Processing`). I thought everything was working well: emails were been sent, the correct data was coming through the emails ... until I realised that the emails were being sent twice.

To troubleshoot this, I skipped the email function, and instead wrote the word *hello* to a custom log file. And indeed *hello* was written twice. Here are some excerpts from my code for my custom module which is currently observing the `sales_order_save_after` event.

**inside config.xml**

```
<events>
    <sales_order_save_after>
        <observers>
            <test_suppliernotification>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>test_mod/observer</class>
                <method>notifySupplier</method>
            </test_suppliernotification>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
```

**inside app/code/local/Test/SupplierNotification/Model/Observer.php**

```
class Test_SupplierNotification_Model_Observer
{
    public function notifySupplier(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $stateProcessing = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING;

        if($order->getState() == $stateProcessing && $order->getOrigData('state') != $stateProcessing) {
            Mage::log("hello", null, 'test_suppliernotification.log');
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**output of var/log/test_suppliernotification.log**

```
2015-10-02T01:17:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): hello
2015-10-02T01:17:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): hello
```

I cannot figure this one out! Has something like this happen to any of you, and if so, how did you solve it? I'm not sure what additional info you may require, so please let me know if you need to see any additional code. I'd really appreciate any assistance in this regard.

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention that for the particular order that I had tested, the Order status moved from *Pending -> Pending Payment -> Processing*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I `donot know`   why this is happing  but ***you can prevent using registry variable*** `(Mage::registry('VARIEABLE'))`.

> ```
> <?php
> class Test_SupplierNotification_Model_Observer
> {
>     public function notifySupplier(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
>
>   /*check registry variable and 
>
>   on first time Mage::registry('prevent_observer') does not save value 
>   So, it will execuate only on first time 
>   */
>   if(!Mage::registry('prevent_observer')):
>       $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
>       $stateProcessing = Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
>    // Assign value to registry variable
>   Mage::register('prevent_observer',true);
>
>       if($order->getState() == $stateProcessing && $order->getOrigData('state') != $stateProcessing) {
>           Mage::log("hello", null, 'test_suppliernotification.log');
>           return true;
>       }
>
>       endif;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi Amit. Thanks! This does work, but I'd like to understand more about this registry setting. Is there any way that when a new order is placed, that my observer won't run at all because of this registry setting?

Comment: Hi again Amit. So after some reading up I found out that registry entries exist only for that request, so be on the safe side I've set my new Registry entries as `Mage::registry('sales_order_save_after_suppliernotification_' . $order->getIncrementId())` ... just to avoid potential duplicate registry entries across simultaneous order placements.

Comment: This **Mage::registry** doesn't work for my 1.9.2.2 version. I used session to store a temporary key which was used to check if the observer run once before, if it does then skip the next execution.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well and used 'sales_order_place_after' event instead. It only calls your function once.